# Два TASK и одна общая переменная

Tags: c#, task

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это лучше организовать.

Есть два отдельных одновременно работающих таска.
Каждый работает в бесконечном цикле, т е все работают постоянно.

Вопрос, как мне лучше организовать переменную, куда 1 таск писал бы, а второй и UI поток читали?

Comment: Ваш код в студию, т.е. в свой вопрос добавьте, пожалуйста. Под тегами есть кнопка Править.

Comment: Обычную ref переменную?

Comment: Прикол, действительно простого ref хватает. Вопрос решён.